# SDM3055 injects 50Hz noise

Tags: noise, multimeter

I am performing some measurements on this circuit (simplified).

[image]

Some details:

1. Power supply is linear
2. Circuit is mounted on a breadboard
3. Oscilloscope connected using a ground spring
4. Oscilloscope and DMM connected to two near main sockets
5. As far as I know, the main sockets should have good ground connection

I noticed that connecting the negative lead of the SDM3055, it injects some 50Hz noise.

This is the output signal when the SDM3055 is not connected:

[image]

This is the output signal when the SDM3055 is connected:

[image]

I have tried:

1. to change the DMM probes
2. twist them together
3. make them shorter (not to much actually)

but apparently nothing reduces the 50Hz noise.

Moreover, I have tried to disconnect the signal generator but even this doesn't make the 50Hz noise disappear.

Apparently, it is indeed the SDM3055 to inject the noise.

Any explanation or suggestion?

Comment: The signal generator and scope are connected to the safety ground. Make sure that the (-) wires from these two devices are connected at the same physical point on your breadboard. (No wire between them).  Then try connecting the (-) lead of the voltmeter to different “grounds” on your breadboard and see what happens.

Comment: Signal Generator (-) and DMM (-) are actually connected at the same physical point. I updated the circuit diagram to show that the DMM (-) cannot connected in other places.

Comment: Are you sure the oscilloscope and signal generator don't both have their (-) connected together via mains earth?

Comment: Hello, Fab: the scope and signal generator’s negative leads are actually connected through their power plug. This means that your circuit diagram is misleading. For example r4 is shorted out.

Comment: @Simon Fitch: This is a good point. As far as I know the oscilloscope (-) is connected to mains earth but I don't know anything about the DMM and the signal generator. I will try this: 1) replace the signal generator with a battery and 2) replace the SDM3055 with a battery powered multimeter (even though less accurate). Thank you both for your help.